# Rails4 + Bootstrap, date picker not showing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I have set a datepicker  on my form using this:

```
<div class="input-group date" id="dp1">
      <%= f.text_field :birthdate, class: "form-control"%>
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

I am firing the js with

```
$('#dp1').datepicker()
```

And my css and js includes are as follow:

css

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap-datepicker";
```

js

```
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require get-shit-done
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

When I click , nothing appears but if I check with inspecting the element, I can se the dropdown being present, switching from `display:none` to `display:block` and being at the correct position.

But there is nothing, so I think the dropdown is there but behind everything else, changing the z-index didn't change anything.

Any idea, why it's doing that and how to solve it?

thanks,

Comment: Have you tried to manually enter `$('#dp1').datepicker()` in the site console? BTW is there anything there (errors)?

Comment: And why do you select the div containing the input that should be datepicker and not the input inself?

Comment: It's because I use the div as an input group.

Comment: If i execute it on the console, it print an html tag and no error

Answer (score 0):

As [bootstrap-datepicker library docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) say:

> ```
> $('.datepicker').datepicker({
>     format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
>     startDate: '-3d'
> })
> ```
>
> Most options may be provided as data-attributes on the target element:
>
> ```
> <input class="datepicker" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
> ```

You must select the input and apply the `datepicker()` to it.

So, as `<%= text_field_tag(:q) %>` will be rendered as `<input id="q" name="q" type="text" />` (view the [rails guides on form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form))

As a result this may help you:

```
$('#dp1 #birthdate').datepicker()
```

Comment: I've try witg specifying the id, and the div as you show, as previously, it generate a ´display:none´ dropdown that change when  I focus the input, but nothing is visible on screen